# Phantom printers on Windows

Tags: printer, network-printer, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a few Windows 2012 R2 servers that all show 300 - 400 printers in `Control Panel` > `Hardware` > `Devices and Printers`.  They also show up as print queues in Device Manager.  Many of them are duplicates - the list in Devices and Printers looks something like this:

```
Printer_A on Print_Server_1
Printer_A on Print_Server_1
Printer_A on Print_Server_1
Printer_A on Print_Server_1
Printer_A on Print_Server_1
Printer_B on Print_Server_1
Printer_B on Print_Server_1
Printer_X on Print_Server_2
Printer_X on Print_Server_2
Printer_X on Print_Server_2
Printer_X on Print_Server_2
```

I can remove the printers in Devices and Printers by selecting a printer and clicking "Remove device".  The printers seem to be removed, but show up again after I logout and log back in.

When I run this I see an empty list (0 printers):

```
c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ge
```

The PowerShell cmdlet `get-printer` lists just **five** printers, as does this:

```
cscript c:\windows\system32\printing_admin_scripts\en-us\prnmngr.vbs -l
```

I see the same five printers under this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers
```

I see 23 connections (none are duplicates) under this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections
```

How can I figure out where these hundreds of printers are coming from so that I can permanently remove them?  The servers are brokered in RDS - could they be getting these printers from each other somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an issue with Windows Server if the server has the RDS role AND is using a remote print server where client-side rendering is enabled.

An easy fix is to add registry entries to enable 15-minute trimming of the printer list, and automatic removal at logout:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider]
"InactiveGuidPrinterAge"=dword:00000384
"ActiveGuidPrinterAge"=dword:00000384
"InactiveGuidPrinterTrim"=dword:00000384
"RemovePrintersAtLogoff"=dword:00000001
```

After adding the above entries, bump the print spooler service and the automatic periodic trimming of printers will begin.

Comment: Are those registry entries on any official Microsoft webpage?